# SPST pin configuration

Tags: pcb, switches, pins

I ordered a SPST switch (Through hole type) from distributors and also download the cad file for PCB layout from the same website. I am now confused with the pin configuration, in the footprints it has 3 holes. Usually the SPST switch has only 2 pins right?. I have gone through the datasheet but I did not understand it completely about the pins because they have the same diagram for SPST and SPDT I suppose.
My question is, if it has 3 pins then what will be the pin connection if I want to just turn ON and OFF the circuit and If it has only 2 pins then which pin should I ignore(delete) in the footprints. I attach the footprints picture and datasheet link with this. Footprints which I downloaded are perfect with the measurements (for 3 Pins). Please let me know if u have any leads on this. Thank you

https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/221/MS-100406-1174115.pdf

[image]

Comment: That datasheet is for a family of switches.  Which SPECIFIC one did you order?  Some have two pins and others have 3.

Comment: I have ordered 10TC605 which is SPST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPST model should only have two pins as can also be seen in the datasheet, although it is not clearly labeled. Removing either pin 1 or 3 should work, since the pin spacing is equal. [image]

Comment: Lets say I consider pin 1 and 2, In this case do i need to worry about the configuration? for example pin 1 should  be connected to supply and pin 2 should be connected to any device (relay or bulb). Or does it work either way. Please let me know

Comment: It'll work either way.